# C# How to sort a List of Strings using lambda expression depending upon a subset of characters inside each item

Tags: c#, list, sorting, lambda

I have a List of Strings which are the names of records.  An example:

```
Record_One
Record_Two
Records_Three
```

Sometimes, I want to delete a record.  For recording purposes, I do not delete the String.  I alter it by adding the word _Deleted to the end such as this:

```
Record_One_Deleted
Record_Two
Record_Three_Deleted
```

My question is this:

How can I keep my List of Strings in alphabetical order, WHILE putting all of the _Deleted records at the bottom?

An intended result would look like (with a new example data set):

```
B
C
D
E
A_Deleted
F_Deleted
```

Note that my list is in alphabetical order, but the strings that contain "_Deleted" are at the bottom.

I wish to use Lambda Expression, because I already can alphabetize a list using something like this:

```
A_List.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name));
```

And I find the one line expressions to be rather slick.

Any thoughts or comments are much appreciated to anyone who may have them!

Comment: You can check x.Name and y.Name for `Deleted` part; if one of them has it, the other should be earlier in the list; if both or neither, just use string.Compare. But I'd just maintain the list of deleted records separately (without changing the model, only how they are represented, probably).

Comment: Thanks for your response! I decided to go with Tim's suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `OrderBy` with a bool:

```
list.OrderBy(str => str.EndsWith("_Deleted"))
    .ThenBy(str => str);
```

Here's a demo: http://ideone.com/m6Zgd

Comment: Won't this actually put `"_Deleted"` rows first or, does `true` come after `false`. The approach is probably good for a one off ordering.

Comment: @Jodrell: Understand `true` as 1 and `false` as 0 ;-) If you would want to have the `true` items first, you could use `OrderByDescending` instead.

Comment: I'd rather leave that to `Comparer<bool>.Default` ;-p

Comment: This is great.  Thanks Tim! That demo site is really something cool!  I  ended up using str.Contains instead of str.EndsWith, but it worked identically from what I could tell!

Comment: @mherr: `EndsWith` is just safer if it's always at the end and also a little bit more efficient(negligible).

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was only slightly deceptive in my question... _Deleted actually appears somewhere in the middle of the string in my application, so that is why I switched it to Contains. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could derive your own [`Comparer<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47.aspx) and pass it to the appropriate [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx) overload.

I believe this would be more efficient than sorting then sub sorting.

---

```
public DeletedLastStringComparer : Comparer<string>
{
    private const string Deleted = "_Deleted";

    private readonly stringComparison;

    public DeletedLastStringComparer() :
        this DeletedLastStringComparer(StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
    {
    }

    public DeletedLastStringComparer(StringComparison stringComparison)
    {
        this.stringComparison;
    }

    public override int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var xDeleted = x.EndsWith(Deleted, this.stringComparison);
        var yDeleted = y.EndsWith(Deleted, this.stringComparison);

        if (xDeleted ^ yDeleted)
        {
            if (xDeleted)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Compare(x, y, this.stringComparison);
        }
    }
}
```

which you could use like this

```
list.OrderBy(s => s, new DeletedLastStringComparer(StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

This has the benefit of being reusable and allowing the best practice of passing an explicit comparison type.

Comment: Thank you for giving a response!  I have decided to go with Tim's suggestion, as it is the one-line solution I was looking for.  However, thank you for bringing to my attention the potential benefits of using this method over Tim's.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea would be something like:

```
A_List.Where(li => !li.EndsWithd("_DELETED").ToList().Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name));
```

but in this example you don't have the deleted items in the list. You can save them in a seperate list an add this list afterwards to the otherone.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give a response!

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use the linq OrderBy Extension and do something like this:

```
 List<string> strings = new List<string>()
            {
                "A",
                "B",
                "C_DELETED",
                "E_DELETED",
                "D",
                "C_DELETED",
            };

 var result = strings.OrderBy(i => i.Replace("_DELETED", string.Empty));
```

Comment: A replace would be a relatively expensive operation.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give a response!